# Sorting merging logic in json javascript

Tags: javascript, json

```
json1 = {
    "t": {
        "o": [{
            "name": "tor",
            "pair": 1
        }],
        "i": [{
            "name": "tiset",
            "pair": 1
        }]
    }
}
json2 = {
    "t": {
        "a": [{
            "name": "tapch",
            "pair": 1
        }],
        "i": [{
            "name": "tiset",
            "pair": 9
        }]
    }
}
```

We have two responses like above. Now I have to merge `json1` and `json2` into a single `json3` like the following:

```
json3 = {
    "t": {
        "a": [{
            "name": "tapch",
            "pair": 1
        }],
        "o": [{
            "name": "tor",
            "pair": 1
        }],
        "i": [{
            "name": "tiset",
            "pair": 9
        }]
    }
}
```

That is, if name would be same then maximum pair will be taken out. I tried a lot but did not get the solution. Could anyone help me out? And I need it as a loop, not a particular hardcoded solution.

Comment: please format your code and show examples of what you tried.  in particular, please show the before/after of what you are expecting.

Comment: May i know what is your question?

Comment: Please post what you have tried. Basically you have to iterate over all objects (it will be a nested loop) and compare the `pair` value.

Comment: for(n1 in yourobj){
    for(n1_1 in yourobj[n1]){
    for(n1_2 in yourobj[n1][n1_1]){
            for(n1_3 in yourobj[n1][n1_1][n1_2]){
      obj[yourobj[n1][n1_1][n1_2].name]=yourobj[n1][n1_1][n1_2].value;
            }
    }
 }
}

Comment: @Parekh: Please **[edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14029612/edit)** and add the code. It's unreadable in comments. Also make sure it actually fits your example. E.g. there is no variable `yourobj` in your example. And: Since this is very related to your previous question, just let me tell you that you won't get far if you ask a question for every tiny bit. If you find yourself asking many questions related to the same thing, take a step back and hit the books again.

Comment: Are you using a JavaScript library such as jQuery, MooTools, etc?

Comment: You could write a recursive clone/merge function which takes a function as Parameter to handle existing properties, to keep it generic. But note that you should distinguish betwee n Arrays and objects,  to use a `for` and a `for in` loop respectively.  But i'm afraid i Won't Do this on mobile right now. Later if noone did this till then

Answer (score 1):

Should be fairly easy.

Just take the first JSON object

```
var json3 = json1;
```

[Edit:] alternative way if you actually want to preserve json1

```
var json3 = {'t':{}};
for (key in json1['t']) {
    json3['t'][key] = json1['t'][key];
}
```

Merge the second object into it

```
for (key in json2['t']) {
    json3['t'][key] = json2['t'][key];
}
```

And you're done

Comment: Just to be precise: You are not *copying* the object, both variables reference the same object.

Comment: I think its only for particular. I need a generalised form

Comment: @user1927722 Then your question isn't really clear about that.

Comment: @user1927722: You can iterate over objects with `for...in` ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in )... what more information do you need?

Answer (score 0):

There you go, it might need some adjustments of handling values that exist, if the first is a primitive value and the second is an Object ( i'll let it be overwritten by the Object) because that wasn't made clear in your question

Primitive values only are handled by a function you pass, but you should understand it by reading the code,

this should come close to what you need.

It will merge all passed Objects into a single one, (the last argument is for the function to handly same primiitve properties ) if a function is passed, it won't iterate over the last one, if not, all parameters will be treated as Object to merge, you can and should adjust this a little, as i didn't care that much about code cleanness right now.

Maybe this helps you to get into the right direction

```
function merge() {
    var srt = typeof arguments[arguments.length - 1] == "function" ? arguments[arguments.length - 1] : function (a, b, prop) {
            return a[prop] > b[prop] ? a[prop] : b[prop];
        };
    var merge = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length - (typeof arguments[arguments.length - 1] == "function" ?1:0); i++)
    inner(arguments[i], merge);

    function inner(obj, mrg) {
        var type = ({}).toString.call(obj);
        if (type == "[object Object]") {
            if (!mrg || typeof mrg != "object" ) mrg = {}; //Well it depends if you want primitive values to be overwritten by an Object or not
            for (var prop in obj)
            if (!mrg[prop] && typeof obj[prop] == "object") mrg[prop] = inner(obj[prop]);
            else if (mrg[prop] && typeof obj[prop] == "object") mrg[prop] = inner(obj[prop], mrg[prop]);
            else if (mrg[prop]) mrg[prop] = srt(mrg, obj, prop);
            else mrg[prop] = obj[prop];

        } else if (type == "[object Array]") {
            if (!mrg) mrg = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++)
            if (!mrg[i] && typeof obj[i] == "object") mrg[i] = inner(obj[i]);
            else if (mrg[i] && typeof obj[i] == "object") mrg[i] = inner(obj[i], mrg[i]);
            else if (mrg[i]) mrg[i] = srt(mrg, obj, i);
            else mrg[i] = obj[i];
        } else {
            // Handle calling of the inner function with a primitive value
        }
        return mrg;
    }
    return merge;
}

var json1 = {
    "t": {
        "o": [{
            "name": "tor",
            "pair": 1
        }],
        "i": [{
            "name": "tiset",
            "pair": 1
        }]
    }
};
var json2 = {
    "t": {
        "a": [{
            "name": "tapch",
            "pair": 1
        }],
        "i": [{
            "name": "tiset",
            "pair": 9
        }]
    }
};

var json3 = merge(json1, json2, {
    a: "test"
}, function (a, b, prop) {
    if (prop == "pair") return a[prop] > b[prop] ? a[prop] : b[prop]; //If the propertie is pair, return the bigger one
    else return b[prop]; //return the to merge Object
});
console.log(json3);
/*{"a": "test", "t": {"a": [{"name": "tapch", "pair": 1}], "i": [{"name": "tiset", "pair": 9}], "o": [{"name": "tor", "pair": 1}]}}*/
```

Here is an example on [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ifuzum/1/edit)

### Comment

To only merge some properties, you could add a parameter which acts as map for the properties
And then iterate if an map is existens, over the maps properties and copy only them.
If not, copy all properties from the Object to merge.

So codewise this could look like this:

```
function merge() {
    var srt = typeof arguments[arguments.length - 1] == "function" ? arguments[arguments.length - 1] : function (a, b, prop) {
            return a[prop] > b[prop] ? a[prop] : b[prop];
        };
    var merge = {};
    var map = arguments[arguments.length - 2]._MAP ? arguments[arguments.length - 2] : false;
    delete map._MAP
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length - (typeof arguments[arguments.length - 1] == "function" ? 1 : 0) - (map ? 1 : 0); i++) {
        inner(arguments[i], merge, map);
    }

    function inner(obj, mrg, map) {
        var type = ({}).toString.call(obj);
        if (type == "[object Object]") {
            if (!mrg || typeof mrg != "object") mrg = {}; //Well it depends if you want primitive values to be overwritten by an Object or not
            for (var prop in map || obj) {
                if (!mrg[prop] && typeof obj[prop] == "object") mrg[prop] = inner(obj[prop], undefined, map[prop]);
                else if (mrg[prop] && typeof obj[prop] == "object") mrg[prop] = inner(obj[prop], mrg[prop], map[prop]);
                else if (mrg[prop]) mrg[prop] = srt(mrg, obj, prop);
                else if (!obj[prop]) return
                else mrg[prop] = obj[prop];
            }

        } else if (type == "[object Array]") {
            if (!mrg) mrg = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < (map || obj).length; i++)
            if (!mrg[i] && typeof obj[i] == "object") mrg[i] = inner(obj[i], undefined, map[i]);
            else if (mrg[i] && typeof obj[i] == "object") mrg[i] = inner(obj[i], mrg[i], map[i]);
            else if (mrg[i]) mrg[i] = srt(mrg, obj, i);
            else mrg[i] = obj[i];
        } else {
            // Handle calling of the inner function with a primitive value
        }
        return mrg;
    }
    return merge;
}

var json1 = {
    "t": {
        "o": [{
            "name": "tor",
            "pair": 1
        }],
        "i": [{
            "name": "tiset",
            "pair": 1
        }]
    }
};
var json2 = {
    "t": {
        "a": [{
            "name": "tapch",
            "pair": 1
        }, {
            a: "a"
        }],
        "i": [{
            "name": "tiset",
            "pair": 9
        }]
    }
};

var json3 = merge(json1, json2, {
    _MAP: true,
    "t": {
        a: [{
            name: true
        },
        false],
        i: false
    }
}, function (a, b, prop) {
    if (prop == "pair") return a[prop] > b[prop] ? a[prop] : b[prop]; //If the propertie is pair, return the bigger one
    else return b[prop]; //return the to merge Object
});
var json4 = merge(json1, json2, {
    _MAP: true,
    "t": {
        a: [false],
        i: false
    }
}, function (a, b, prop) {
    if (prop == "pair") return a[prop] > b[prop] ? a[prop] : b[prop]; //If the propertie is pair, return the bigger one
    else return b[prop]; //return the to merge Object
});
console.log(json3, json4);

/*{"t": {"a": [{"name": "tapch"}, {"a": "a"}], "i": [{"name": "tiset", "pair": 9}]}}*/
/*{"t": {"a": [{"name": "tapch", "pair": 1}], "i": [{"name": "tiset", "pair": 9}]}}*/
```

As you see

- `json3` was created, passing a map which should copy the following:

  - Object `t`

    - Array `a`

      - Element `0` of `a`
      - Propertie `name` of element `0`
      - The whole element `1`
    - The whole Array `i`
- `json4` was created, passing a map which should copy the following:

  - Object `t`

    - Array `a`
    - The whole element `0` of `a`
    - The whole Array `i`

As you see the other properties haven't been copied

Here is another [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ugugix/1/edit), just take a look and fiddle a bit (and read the code)

Comment: Thanks Glut !! Its very useful but what to do if i want to merge some selected object not whole objects

Comment: @ParekhShah Updated the answer, i hope you did mean merge some selected properties of Objects into one